# using msvc c library to compile a gcc library

Tags: c, gcc

Is it possible to do that in the first place? Currently I'm including the header locations of the required libraries in the compile command but am getting a lot of errors over stdint.h which the msvc library parts are using. It says "use this header only with microsoft visual c++ compilers!"

So maybe if I compiled the msvc libraries first and then included the .lib files it would work? How would I do that anyway?

EDIT:
What I'm trying to compile is a bit of a mess. It was an old nix c library, partially translated to compile on win32 msvc some years back and then partially translated again (from the original and other parts) to compile on win32 gcc. This was done way before my time.

What I need to do is restore functionality to a few functions in the library and put a c++ cli wrapper around it to be usable from .net. Since the msvc part was much bigger, I took that as the basis of my project but one of the parts I need is in the gcc spinoff. So basically I'm trying to compile the required msvc libraries to support the gcc library to support the msvc++ cli project. I'm inexperienced with the gcc and makefile side of things hence my confusion.

Comment: Please give more details on what you are trying to compile and what precise steps you are doing. And focus your question I don't know what youre really asking??

Comment: You need to provide specifics on what you're actually *doing*, not just what you're trying to accomplish.  The actual compile command that produces the error would be a good place to start.